# Ethical to add a newspaper article that does not include my name to my CV

Tags: career-development, ethics, legal

I recently worked on a product that got my company some really beefy profits. I was part of the 12 member team which created it and I exclusively had about 30% of the influence on the project.

Now since the product is gaining popularity, it is also featured in the local newspapers distributed across my city. Although, my name isn't mentioned in any of the articles, would it be ethical to add a link of the article to my resume?

I am afraid that if I ask my manager, he would say no.

Could it get me into legal trouble?

Comment: An article really doesn't belong on your resume which should be a short one or two page document of highlights, not clippings. I recall people saying that this is the kind of stuff you put on your LinkedIn though.

Comment: @Lilienthal I was talking about a link to the article. I see a lot of people having "In the news" section in their resume`.

Comment: What an interviewer will think is "The youngest, most junior member who has been there 3 months influenced 30% of the product?"

Comment: I guess I am good at what I do :)  I have appraisal letters from several partners on my email though.

Comment: Where did the 30% come from? What was the other eleven people doing?

Comment: Probably better to reference the article in a cover letter if it is applicable to the job. Be careful about saying "30%" or any other quantitative metric unless it can be easily and independently verified by your interviewer. Although the stock advice is to give "numbers" for achievements that almost never works out in practice simply because such numbers can't be checked and they often measure subjective attributes. Interviewers will start doing arithmetic in their heads and create doubt (Ed Heal just gave an example).

Comment: I've never seen an "in the news" section - at least, not on developers' resumes. If this is something on LinkedIn, be careful - an actual resume submitted for a job position is not the same as a LinkedIn profile.

Answer (score 8):

If you aren't lying than it is completely ethical.

When I see names around new products I would expect to see the originator and maybe some company owners/higher-ups.  Your name being omitted is unfortunate but really a fact of life - you did not have enough weight at your company to get your name included.  Really the only way this is even a little fishy is if an article gave a comprehensive list of people developing the product and your name was off - then anyone would have a hard time buying that you did 30%.

But as it stands you worked on it.  You can tell exactly what you did on the project and reference any article.  If I am hiring a tech person who worked on a big product like this I would expect them to be looking for a job if they did that much work and weren't even mentioned.  Really it is the norm in our industry and is a bit sad but often project managers get more credit than the people doing the real innovation.  Put the full truth on your CV and just be willing to back it up.

Comment: I am the youngest and the junior most level employee. Besides I have been working here since the past 3 months. The article only mentions the company name and not the employee names.

Answer (score 3):

Ethical, yes. Effective? Not so sure.

A brief description of the project's context and importance ("leading veeblefetzer; won Frob Award") and a good description of what you did to make it a success would probably impress me more.

If you'd been cited as a leading member of the team, or if you'd said something particularly articulate about it, that might be more worthwhile. As it is, I'd suggest that you come to the interview prepared to talk about the project's significance and what you did for it that illustrates what you can bring to this next job.

I can always look up the product. I can't look you up (usually), and I definitely can't look up what you contributed to that effort, and those are what you're trying to sell.

Caveat: I'm an engineer. My ideas of what would impress a manager may be incorrect. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> would it be ethical to add a link of the article to my resume?

As you say you had done a significant part of the project, you very well can.

> But, how can you prove yourself?

Write how and what work you did in that project. Write about your role in it, clearly.  As blankip said, `Put the full truth on your CV and just be willing to back it up`

**A suggestion:**  Sometimes, companies really don't like(or prefer) such practices. So, have a word with your manager who was in-charge when you were working on the project.

**A tip:** Start by praising the project and how it really deserved it's worthy acclaim in the news article, and how his leadership helped achieve that. This would help you earn brownie points, and then make the actual request. < This is just a tip, you may or may not use it. >